# How to make $_GET function work with Rewritten url?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, printf, author

i tried using

```
$_GET['glossary']
```

function in wordpress functions.php to hide certain path of specific post for following domain

https://sampledomain.com?glossary=extrathing

Here is the full code of this

```
if ($_GET['glossary']){
         printf('<style>.author-box{display:none;}</style>');
}
```

It worked perfect and hide the author-box for specific post.

however when i did activated permalink in wordpress that changed url to

https://sampledomain.com/glossary/extrathing/

the above function of $_GET no more working, any suggestion on it please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change if condition to check uri

```
if ($_GET['glossary'] || $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/glossary/extrathing/'){
         printf('<style>.author-box{display:none;}</style>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, i tried and it worked for fixed url like /glossary/extrathing/, how about there are many urls like /glossary/extrathing/ or /glossary/manythings/ and i want to detect in url /glossary/ only ?

Comment: than `if ($_GET['glossary'] || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/glossary/' === 0) ...` :)

Answer (score 0):

Use get_query_var('glossary') for rewritten URL,